# Empty Base Optimisation MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Empty base optimisation with multiple inheritance appears still to be broken in msvc++ 2010. Currently, it appears to only work for the first type derived from, so if you are deriving from multiple empty bases the child type ends up with more bytes (just useless padding!) than it needs.

Apparently it's been this way for some time: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/100686/empty-member-optimization-not-working-properly

This link is marked "closed - not to be fixed". Just wondering if anyone knew if there's anything happening with this "feature" these days??

Comment: While the comments are 4 years old, all that code that could break hasn't gone away.  So they are probably going to stick it out until they have a real opportunity to make a clean break from existing binaries.

Comment: Is there a good reason "a large amount" of existing code would be reliant on objects being bigger than they should be??

Comment: It doesn't matter if the reason is good or not.  That the code exists is sufficient for MS to have decided making a breaking change is not worth it.  It is also entirely possible they are referring more to the necessary ABI change that would accompany it, but that's not something I've ever really had to mess with.

Comment: Some people do use a `write(p, n)` approach to binary serialisation... messing with object sizes and offsets therein will break deserialisation of existing dumps.  That said, I haven't bothered to read the MS page... just speculation and a thought re the comments above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Empty base optimisation with multiple inheritance appears still to be broken in msvc++ 2010

What do you mean by "broken"? That, it is not Standard conformant?

The Standard doesn't require empty classes to have zero size when deriving from them. An implementation may choose to optimize this or it may not at all.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe I should have said "sub-optimal" rather than "broken".

Comment: @Darren: Even then, my answer still holds correct, as the Standard doesn't require compilers to optimize empty base classes. They may or may not do the optimization at all.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but obviously there was an attempt to implement EBO in msvc, so whether it's in the standard or not, it's at least "interesting" that it was only half done. I'm not writing code that explicitly requires sizeof(data) to equal something specific, it's just less memory efficient if EBO doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Darren: There are too many things that MSVC didn't implement, even those which are required by the Standard. If that is so, then it's not a big deal if it didn't optimize empty bases.