# Template specialization struct size

Tags: c++, templates

I'm experiencing an - at least to me - strange behavior when applying the `sizeof` operator to a template specialization.
Consider these declarations:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

template <bool enable>
struct RGB_data {
    typedef unsigned char typeRGB;
    typeRGB R;
    typeRGB G;
    typeRGB B;
};
template <> struct RGB_data<false> {};

template <bool enable>
struct XYZ_data {
    typedef float type3D;
    type3D X;
    type3D Y;
    type3D Z;
};
template<> struct XYZ_data<false> {};

template <bool enable>
struct Alpha_data {
    typedef unsigned char typeAlpha;
    typeAlpha A;
};
template<> struct Alpha_data<false> {};

template <bool enable>
struct Confidence_data {
    typedef unsigned char typeConfidence;
    typeConfidence C;
};
template<> struct Confidence_data<false> {};


template <
    bool enableXYZ,
    bool enableRGB,
    bool enableC,
    bool enableA
>
struct Pixel :
    public XYZ_data<enableXYZ>,
    public RGB_data<enableRGB>,
    public Alpha_data<enableA>,
    public Confidence_data<enableC>
{};

typedef Pixel<true,false,false,false> Pixel3D;
typedef Pixel<true,false,true,false> Pixel3Dc;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

However, the size of the `Pixel3Dc` struct is 14 bytes; the size of `Pixel3D` is 14 bytes as well. The sizes of the data types in use are 1 and 4 for `unsigned char` and `float`, respectively.

Where are the additional bytes, and how can I achieve a struct size that matches with the size of the contained data?

Environment is VS 9.0, Windows7 x64, Compiled to 32Bit, Debug & Release mode.

Comment: Are you sure that VS9 takes `#pragma push` into account for templates?

Comment: @filmor I don't think templates have anything to do with this.  And without `#pragma pack`, the size is 16, not 14 (since the compiler has to guarantee that the size be a multiple of 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution, but at least part of the reason for
extra bytes is that a type cannot have a size of 0; even an
empty struct or class (e.g. like `Alpha_data<false>`) will have
a size of at least one.  On the other hand, you *are* deriving
from them, so the empty base class optimization (which allows
a base class to have an effective size of 0, even if `sizeof`
reports more) should apply.  Apparently, MSC is only applying
it to one of the bases, probably the first.  Otherwise, you'd
get a size of 15.

Probably not much help to you, but g++ gives sizes of 12 and 13,
which corresponds to applying the empty base class optimization
to all of the bases.

Unless someone knows of an option to make MSC be more aggressive
in applying the empty base class optimization, your options are
to report this as a bug to Microsoft, hoping they'll be
comprehensive (since the standard doesn't require that the empty
base class optimization be used at all), or switch to g++.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. It seems that this 'bug' has been around for a while now (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701469/why-empty-base-class-optimization-is-not-working, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119927/empty-base-optimisation-msvc), so probably no use reporting it to MS. I'm sure we'll find another (maybe non-template) solution.

Comment: @Matz You can keep the templates at the user level.  (It may be more convenient for client code to write `typedef Pixel<true,false,false,false> Pixel3D;` than to use a different name for the class.)  Just don't provide a default implementation, but rather specializations for each possible instantiation (generated from some sort of a script).